Extending Node's global object with a declaration file in Typescript
I want to add a property to the global object in a Next 14 project, the type declaration would be something like:
declare module global {
  var IS_REACT_ACT_ENVIRONMENT: boolean
}

or
declare var global: typeof globalThis & {
  IS_REACT_ACT_ENVIRONMENT: boolean
}

both of these declarations work if I put them in a typescript file before accessing the new property, but if I put them in a global.d.ts declaration file it seems they're not detected.
This is puzzling me because I placed global.d.ts in the same folder where I have other declaration files and the types contained on those other files are successfully checked without need of an explicit export/import.
Note that the include array in my tsconfig.json includes the pattern **/*.ts. Also, my declaration files are all placed in a /src/types folder and named with the {SOMEVALUE}.d.ts pattern.
(I found there's a globals.global.d.ts file in the types for Node, I don't know if that is taking precedence on my file or how it would do that).
Is there a specific method to extend the global object interface using declaration files?
